# Role - edit page but not publish

Tags: pages, admin

I am pretty new at Wordpress.. So I have this problem:
I need a user role that has the rights as a contributor but for pages. As I have no posts in my website the users will have to edit pages. Every user should be able to edit his own page but before the changes go online an admin has to review it.

I already tried "User Role Editor" Plugin. There I managed every user to be able to edit his own page but if I enable 'edit_published_pages' he can update the pages without an admin having a look at it. If I disable he cannot edit any page as they are published..

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok sorry after a long time I found this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/revisionary/